# unix shell programming if statement condtion setting

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to set filename upper to lower and lower to upper i dont know how to use "and" operation in shell programming.

```
if [ $temp == "[a-z]" ]
if (( (($temp >= 'a')) && (($temp <= 'z')) ))
if [[ (($temp >= 'a')) && (($temp <= 'z')) ]]
```

I tried these three if statement but no one worked well. What should i do

Comment: This looks like parts if a `Regular Expression` to me. Either you have to check for all chars manually it try some regular expression as you already have parts of it.

Comment: we need to see some sample data and expected output, given those inputs. Please update your Q with this information (don't reply in comments, thank you!). And. .... Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [ "$temp" \> 'a' ] && [ "$temp" \< 'z' ] || [ "$temp" = 'a' ] || [ "$temp" = 'z' ]  ; then
  echo 'true 1'
fi

if [ "$temp" \> 'a' -a "$temp" \< 'z' -o "$temp" = 'a' -o "$temp" = 'z' ]  ; then
  echo 'true 2'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string (filename) with a character.
When you just want to change the case of the filename, you can use:

```
file="FileWithUpAndDowns"

    echo "Tr gives ${file}" | tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]'
    # or use typeset
    typeset -u  upperfile
    typeset -l  lowerfile
    upperfile="${file}"
    lowerfile="${file}"
    echo "Low=${lowerfile}"
    echo "Up=${upperfile}"
```

Answer (score 0):

bash glob patterns understand POSIX character classes, so to test for a lower case character:

```
if [[ $temp == [[:lower:]] ]]; then ...
```

The key is to leave the right-hand side *unquoted* to have the shell treat it like a pattern. If it's quoted, it will be considered a literal string. Note this behaviour is *only* for the `[[ double bracket ]]` form.

However, as you say you want to swap case, this is straightforward:

```
swapped=$( tr '[:lower:][:upper:]' '[:upper:][:lower:]' <<<"$str" )
```